# Microsoft Graph: Get order of tasks in a Planner bucket

Tags: graph, microsoft-planner

I am using Microsoft Graph to request all tasks of a Planner Plan's bucket with:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/{plan-id}/tasks

According to the docs, the order of the tasks should be given by the property key "orderHint", but sorting by the values does not result in the order I see in the web app. Moreover, when changing the order of tasks in the web app, the values of orderHint don't change, they seem to be static.

What's the proper way to get the order of tasks in a bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the tasks on the bucket board is based on the orderhint field on the bucketTaskBoardFormat resource (Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannerbuckettaskboardtaskformat?view=graph-rest-1.0).

For further information on how to actually manipulate the orderhint fields, there is a good article that explains the nuances: https://laurakokkarinen.com/how-to-sort-tasks-using-planner-order-hint-and-microsoft-graph/

Comment: For the records: With this extension the proper can be fetched in one request:
[link](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/{plan-id}/tasks?$expand=bucketTaskBoardFormat($select=orderHint))